# How do you in Groovy parse a String and convert it into a Map type?

Tags: parsing, dictionary, groovy

How do I in the most efficient and secure way in groovy be able to extract:

```
to: ["example1@example.com", "example2@example.com"], from: "example3@example.com", subject: "example", bodyText: "Hello"
```

from:

```
This is an example - to: ["example1@example.com", "example2@example.com"], from: "example3@example.com", subject: "example", bodyText: "Hello"
```

and then convert it into a Map type. I tried searching but I can’t find exactly what I’m looking for. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: It seems that regexp will be the most appropriate here - nothing new :/

Comment: for the map part: find out, who sends you this and then ask them, what format it is. if it's JSON then parse it as JSON etc.. next ask them how a ` - ` in the `This is an example` would be quoted or if `to:` is _always_ on first place (which it might not, if it's JSON e.g.).

Answer (score 1):

You can verify this solution by running it in the Groovy console

```
def input = 'to: ["example1@example.com", "example2@example.com"], from: "example3@example.com", subject: "example", bodyText: "Hello"'
input = "[$input]"

Map map = Eval.me(input)

assert map.to == ['example1@example.com', 'example2@example.com']
assert map.from == 'example3@example.com'
```